# .onClick javascript function - hide when hover out

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have this simple jsfiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/fLp74gnu/
As the example says, the onlclick function shows/hides the `download-icon` element. How to show on click and hide on hover out?

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("main-cell");
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    parents[i].onclick = function () {
        toggleChildren(this);
    };
}

function toggleChildren(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i] == elem) {
            for (var ii = 1; ii <= 5; ii++) {
                if (divs[i + ii].style.display == "none") {
                    divs[i + ii].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    divs[i + ii].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.main-cell {
    background: #bbb;
    width: 200px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 7%;
}
.main-cell:hover {
    background: #999;
}
.download-icon {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 7%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cell">
    <div class="download-icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't rely on just a jsfiddle - please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question

Comment: Do you want to remove the download-icon class on hover ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.

```
.main-cell {
    background:transparent;/*set to transparent so the user can't see it but the element will still have height and width*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 7%;
}
.main-cell:hover {
    background: #999;/*the element is visible but when the user hovers over it it will take a color and reappear*/
}
```

Comment: That's not a thing I wanted. I want to hide only "download-icon" element when hovering out of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like following:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLp74gnu/2/)

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");   
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("main-cell");
for (var i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {
    parents[i].onclick = function() { toggleChildren(this); console.log(this);};
    parents[i].onmouseleave = function(){
        this.removeChild(document.getElementById('DELETEME'));
    };
}
function toggleChildren(elem) {
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length;i++) {
        if (divs[i] == elem) {
            for (var ii=1; ii<=5; ii++) {
                if (divs[i+ii].style.display == "none") {
                    divs[i+ii].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    divs[i+ii].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.main-cell {
  background: #bbb;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 7%;
}
.main-cell:hover {
  background: #999;
}
.download-icon {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 7%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cell"><div ID="DELETEME" class="download-icon"></div></div>
```

Is that the behaviour ? ( may be you only want to remove the class ? )

Edit:

```
parents[i].onmouseleave = function(){
        var el = this.getElementsByTagName('div');
        el[0].classList.remove('download-icon');
    };
    parents[i].onmouseover = function(){
        var el = this.getElementsByTagName('div');
        el[0].classList.add('download-icon');
        // el[0].style.display = "none"; if you want ed to appear in that way
    };
```

In this way you are not removing the element but the class. ( and adding it again ).

Comment: @t4dohx you're welcome. If you want to remove only the class you can take a look to my edit part.